# CodeIgniter: название функций в контроллерах

Tags: codeigniter, функции

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста! Можно ли в контролере, в название функции подставить значение из БД. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Можно её даже вызвать. С помощью [рефлексии из дефолтного пхп](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.reflection.php). 
Самый элементарный [пример](http://codepad.org/HltBY7Wt):

```
$str = "myFuncName";
$str();
```

Но лучше обезопасить себя с помощью знаний по той ссылке, что я Вам прикинул.

Comment: Спасибо! Посмотрю!

Comment: @leviatan, если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Comment: пока не знаю, на сколько ответ исчерпывающий. Я пока эксперементирую с разными вариантами. Как только получится я сразу отмечу или прокоментирую.

Comment: @leviatan, так же Вы можете воспользоваться [call_user_func][1]. В комментариях к этой странице присутствуют довольно полезные сниппеты. Но с т.з. ООП всё же правильнее использовать Reflection Class.

[1]:http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func.php